# How do i re-install or fix "libmp3lame"?

Tags: audio

**Unknown Encoder "llibmp3lame"**
I get this error when i try to do anything audio related, like stripping audio for a video in youtube dl, or using a spotdl (A spotify downloader) to download music.

> 

```
Draig@ibk:~/Documents$ spotdl -s "No good Nina"
INFO: Downloading "No good Nina"
INFO: Downloading to "The Butlers - No Good Nina.mp3"
  0%|                                | 0/4464KiB [00:00<?, ?KiB/s]Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
  0%|                     | 16/4464KiB [00:00<00:01, 3356.11KiB/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Draig/.local/bin/spotdl", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/Draig/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotdl/command_line/__main__.py", line 25, in main
    exitcode = spotdl_handler.match_arguments()
  File "/home/Draig/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotdl/command_line/core.py", line 69, in match_arguments
    self.download_track(track)
  File "/home/Draig/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotdl/command_line/core.py", line 233, in download_track
    return self.download_track_from_metadata(metadata)
  File "/home/Draig/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotdl/command_line/core.py", line 334, in download_track_from_metadata
    encoder=encoder,
  File "/home/Draig/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotdl/track.py", line 59, in download_while_re_encoding
    process.stdin.write(chunk)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Draig@ibk:~/Documents$ youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svahuHajzY4
[youtube] svahuHajzY4: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: Dennis Lloyd - Alien (Lyrics)-svahuHajzY4.webm
[download] 100% of 2.30MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Destination: Dennis Lloyd - Alien (Lyrics)-svahuHajzY4.mp3
ERROR: audio conversion failed: Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
Draig@ibk:~/Documents$
```

Its driving me nuts, please help out
Also new to stackexchange, let me know if something is off.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt purge libmp3lame-dev
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install libmp3lame-dev
```

eventually without -dev, I mean libmp3lame only. I do not remember the correct name.

Comment: The first thing i thought of my man, but apparently libmp3lame is not the same as -dev and it comes inside some package, it was truly wierd and that's why i ended up posting this on stack exchange. Good news however i solved it a while ago

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it myself
The root of the problem was, even after uninstallation of ffmpeg, the ffmpeg which came with elementary os, was not purged. Some godsend guy somewhere on the internet suggested i locate ffmpeg and rename it to .old, after that i ended reinstalling a bunch of packages "individually".
Eventually worked.